# Quando fecho o Form executa o evento do Leave

Tags: c#

Na minha aplicação criei um evento `Leave` no `maskCnpj`, quando fecho o meu form tenho que clicar 3 vezes na janela `messageBox` tem alguma maneira de acertar isso?

```
if (maskCnpj.Text != "  .   .   /    -")
{
    lblAjuda2.Text = "";
    ValidaDocEmailModel ObjValidaDoc = new ValidaDocEmailModel();

    cnpj = new ValidaDocEmailModel().DuplicidadeCNPJ(maskCnpj.Text);

    if (ObjValidaDoc.ValidaCNPJ(maskCnpj.Text))
    {
         if (cnpj)
         {
            lblAjuda2.Text = "Este CNPJ já existe !!!!!!!";
            CarregarCamposCnpjExixtente();
            DesabilitarCampos();

         }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("este cnpj já é inválido ");
        lblAjuda2.Text = "O CNPJ é Inválido, por favor digite um CNPJ válido";
        modo = "Salvar";
        maskCnpj.Focus();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("O CNPJ não pode ser Vazio !!!!!!");
    maskCnpj.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mude sua condição no if para somente maskCnpj.Text != "", não há necessidade de verificar os caracteres se você vai fazer a máscara depois, e está parecendo que a função do focus() está persistindo a mensagem, até um momento que você consegue clicar para fechar o form mais rápido do que a função é executada.